# Handling category-specific attributes of items in a database with a PK referencing a FK

Tags: database-design, model, foreign-keys, primary-key

Suppose there are a set of attributes common to all `Item`, like `ItemName` and `ItemImage`.

Further suppose that you know in advance that there will be a few specific distinctions of `Item` (they could overlap) that require specific columns. For instance, `ToyItem` has a special column `MinimumAge` and `CarItem` has a special column `NumWheels`.

I want to handle this in the database as follows: create `Item` table with a primary key `ItemId`. Create `ToyItem` table whose primary key REFERENCES `ItemId` in `Item`. Create a `CarItem` table whose primary key also REFERENCES `ItemId` in `Item`.

So my questions are:

1. Is it reasonable to use a single foreign key as the primary key of the sub-item tables?
2. Is there another approach to the design that could keep track of all the different types of `Item`? Right now I have to know in advance what these are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your needs. Specifically on how you plan to look for data.
If you want to look for any kind of Item by their attributes from the `Item` table your layout is not too unreasonable. I would still suggest a different strategy, which is also easily extensible:

Keep your `Item` table and add only 1 more table called `Attr`. In `Attr` you can then have 2 data fields, `name` and `value` as well as a foreign key to `Item`. If you want you can also make `Attr.name` of type `enum` so only allowed attributes can be added to the main "object" in `Item`.

The other approach would be to have tables for each sub-type like `Toy` or `Car` and reference those to `Item` (instead of the other way around).

In any case you can `JOIN` these tables easily enough, so it's really up to you there.

Comment: so which way are you going?

Comment: I am going to stick with the approach of a table per subclass, since there won't be many subclasses. If I go with the first approach you suggest, the "specialness" of subclasses will not be clear from viewing the scheme... if that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Toy Items and Car Items are subclasses of the class Items.  See the following

[Relational database design multiple user types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749525/relational-database-design-multiple-user-types/13752304#13752304)

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like they describe the same "shared primary key" approach so I feel a bit better about it