# How to store subscriptions of different types of customers - database design

Tags: database-design

I am designing subscription based database for website. There will be 2 types of subscribers, schools and students.

Since schools and students will contain different data, I decide to create 2 different tables, named school and student.

I am now about to create the table subscription, and I am considering the following options:

Option 1: I could create table clientgroup as following:

```
clientgroup
=====================================
clientgroupID
clientgroupName (schools, students)
```

Then the table client as following:

```
client
=====================================
clientID
clientgroupID
clientOriginalID // The id from student or school table.
```

Then the subscription table:

```
subscription
===================================== 
subscriptionID
paymentID
clientID
subscriptionStartsAt
subscriptionEndsAt
subscriptionIsActive
subscriptionHasExpired
```

and on the end the payment table:

```
payment
=====================================
paymentID
clientID
paymentDateTime
paymentAmount
paymentIpAddress
paymentSessionID
```

The other option that I am considering is to not create the tables clientgroup and client, just to crate separate tables for the subscriptions and payments for both groups, students and schools.

Which of those 2 options is better? Pros and cons for both? Any other suggestions - options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749525/relational-database-design-multiple-user-types/13752304#13752304