# database design best practice connecting multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

sorry if this question has been asked heaps before, but I didn't know how to word it in a way that google would be able to understand.

Basically if for example you have 3 tables:

Table A

Table B1

Table B2

and the data from all 3 tables are connected in 1 of 2 ways either:

Table A & Table B1

OR

Table A & Table B2

Which would be best practice to connect them in a table and why?

1 table such as:

Joined table

```
    |Table A  |Table B1  |Table B2  |
    |tableA_ID|tableB1_ID|null      |
    |tableA_ID|null      |tableB2_ID|
```

or have 2 seperate tables for each join

Table A and B1 joined

Table A and B2 joined

Or is there another better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749525/relational-database-design-multiple-user-types/13752304#13752304

Comment: Thanks Walter, after some playing with it yesterday I had kind of come to the same conclusion, this helps clarify my thoughts on it. how can I accept this as the answer...?

Comment: It's already accepted as the correct answer over in its original context.  I decided against posting a redundant answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Joining table depends upon the Fields and Relationship among the tables.
It also depends on the output you are looking - based on this you will need to join the tables

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join`, two in fact:

```
select a.tableA_ID, b1.tableB1_ID, b2.tableB2_ID
from a left join
     b1
     on a.tableA_ID = b1.tableA_ID left join
     b2
     on a.tableA_ID = b2.tableA_ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but given your expected results, `union all` might work:

```
select a.tableA_ID, 
       b.tableB1_ID as TableB1, 
       null as TableB2
from a join b on a.tableA_ID = b.tableA_ID
union all
select a.tableA_ID, 
       null,
       b2.tableB2_ID
from a join b2 on a.tableA_ID = b2.tableA_ID
```