# Multiple tables always queried together vs One table that hold multiple "types"

Tags: database-design

I have 4 types of Posts. They are *always* going to be queried together. The data they contain is slightly different. Something like this:

```
LinkPost(title, url)
ImagePost(title, image_file)
EventPost(title, location, start_time, end_time)
TextPost(title, body)
```

My solutions are to:

1. Have 4 tables, and always query them together, but this creates performance issues since I'll mostly want them ordered by date, or a score (stored in a column).
2. Have 5 tables. The 4 from solution 1, plus a Post table that just has post_id, post_type, created_at, score. This would allow me to query one table, and look up the data in the other tables.
3. Just stick everything in one table `Post(type, title, url, image_file, location, start_time, end_time, body)`. This would allow me to index, and query things easily.

Assuming that I'll only ever have a handful of post "types", and each one will only have a handful of columns (meaning only about 5-10 columns would be "unused" for any given row). Is there any reason, other than not being 3NF, to not put everything in one table? Is there a name for this type of pattern?

Comment: just stick everything in one table Post(type, title, url, image_file, location, start_time, end_time, body)

Comment: Your question may be answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749525/relational-database-design-multiple-user-types/13752304#13752304

Comment: Why do you have four tables? Have you simplified them leaving out other fields? It would appear the data you show are all dependent on `title`, so it would be fine to have all in one table.