# Databases & Shared Primary Key?

Tags: mysql, database, web, database-design

Ok so I am designing a database for my website I am making, which will host information about different things, (a bit like IMDb).

I will have 'movie' pages, 'tv' pages & pages for 'actors', 'directors' and possibly writers.

Now I originally came up with something along the lines of this:
Film {
  MediaID:  #One media type (film/tv) will have one ID
  Description:  #One film will have one description
  Cert.UK:
  Cert.US:  #One film may have a certificate for each country
  IMDb:  #One film will have one IMDb rating
  Duration:  #One film will have one duration
  Release:  #One film will have on release
  Genre:  #A movie may belong to multiple genres
  People.ActorID  #One film may have multiple actors
  People.DirectorID  #One film may have multiple directors
  Image:  #One film will have one image
  Trailer:  #One Film will have one trailer
}

Cert {
  UK:
  US:
}

People {
  PeopleID:  #One person will have one ID
  Role:  #A person may have multiple roles
  Film.MediaID:  #A person may belong to multiple films
  Name:  #One person will have one name
  DOB:  #One person will have one Date of Birth
  Description:  One person will have one description
}

For the case of MediaID in Film; both Film and Tv tables will share MediaID as their primary keys, and I don't want to make a Media table and add Type:Film/TV as they require different columns leaving alot of unncecesary null data. Is it ok to leave that as is?

Also:
When adding a new film, how can I make sure it's MediaID doesn't already exist?
When there is a one to many relationship do I need to create a new table? For example I thought about creating a roles and genre table but would that be necessary?

Comment: If you have Film and Tv sharing ID then yes it is common to separate the key out to a separate table, let the DB auto-assign a value on insert, use that key as a foreign key in your other tables.

Comment: Your question may have an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749525/relational-database-design-multiple-user-types/13752304#13752304