# Database design for social media app: Handling multiple post types and timeline creation performance

Tags: database-design, relational-database, single-table-inheritance, class-table-inheritance, shared-primary-key

We're designing a relational database for a social media-like application. In this application, we have 7 different types of posts, each with 2-3 unique fields. To simplify development, we're considering storing all these fields in a single entity called `PostContent` instead of querying and sorting them separately based on the post type when creating a timeline.

However, this approach leads to a significant number of `null` values in our database.

Additionally, in our system, we'll create a new timeline for the communities it's associated with and their users every time when a post is created.

Since the timeline creation service will be heavily used in our app, would our current approach cause serious performance issues? What would be the best way forward in this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relational database design multiple user types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749525/relational-database-design-multiple-user-types)

Comment: @LeonardoHysesani Thanks for suggestion but I don't think it is a duplicate entirely. In my question, main issue is creation service is heavily used and if there is a bottleneck in design it is important that where that is. So I'll add tags in that question's answer and select not duplicate as a feedback.